# Are two text files identical except lines that start with special characters C#

Tags: c#, file, text, compare

I have two text files that represent settings of the same computer, however I am creating them at different times so the row of the date will always change.
Since this will be on multiple computers, I cannot rely on the row number, however I do know that the unnecessary info lines to check the difference is `;`.
How do I compare and say if the two files are identical efficiently but ignore lines that start with `;` in the compresence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following LINQ query:

```
var file1Lines = File.ReadLines(path1).Where(l => !l.StartsWith(";"));
var file2Lines = File.ReadLines(path2).Where(l => !l.StartsWith(";"));
bool identical = file1Lines.SequenceEqual(file2Lines);
```

[`SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-7.0) takes the order into account. If that's not desired use a [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.setequals?view=net-7.0):

```
bool identical = file1Lines.ToHashSet().SetEquals(file2Lines);
```

If you want to compare in a case insensitive manner, so treat `A` same as `a`, you have to pass `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to `ToHashSet` (or to `SequenceEqual`).

Comment: I'm curious, for this solution, would the line items need to be in the same positions, or does SequenceEqual not care about the order?

Comment: @NickScotney: it cares about the order. I just added a solution if you want to ignore the order

Comment: Thanks @Tim Schmelter - OP didn't specify if both files were the same order or not, so thought I'd raise it

Comment: The order of setting shouldn't change on the same computer. I'm curious though how efficient ToHashSet is on a text file that is around 15KB (around 700 lines)?

Comment: @Yuki1112: A `HashSet<T>` is very efficient in lookups(O(1)). You just need temporarily more memory to create that collection of unique lines. So if the file contains millions of lines you should rely on a diffferent approach, but for 700 lines it's perfect.

Comment: Thank you, my files won't pass the 1.5K lines (worst case) so this is great. I believe it will be safer not to care about the order of lines since the content compresence (checking the setting are the same) will be safer in my case

Comment: @Yuki1112: Note that, if you want to compare in a case insensitive manner, so treat `A` same as `a`, you can use a similar approach. But you have to pass `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to `ToHashSet` (or to `SequenceEqual`).